# Sort order table of data within Power Automate

Tags: html, dax, html-lists, power-automate

I having connected my Power Automate to a Power BI report dataset, using the Run a query against a dataset tool, so I get a table of data.

[image]

How do I add a sort order to this output? I want to sort my data by column1.

I tried

```
DEFINE
VAR _My Table = 
SELECTCOLUMNS( column1, column2, 
)
Evaluate _My Table 
Order by column1 DESC
```

But this did not work.